Outline of mesh showing with alpha
Im using a texture with alpha data to make parking lines, the mesh is just a plane and im using the texture coordinate's to scale and offset things, but as you can see there's still a clear outline/cutoff of the plane. I've switched the alpha to pre multiplied, turned transparent shadows in the material off and in object data turned off the shadow in ray visibility. I am also using cycles for the rendering




Looks like there are two planes, one over the other, one with transparency, introducing some impredictable Z - fighting.
Instead, you could create  a copy of the asphalt material, add the lines (with screen blending method, in my example), and assign it to the interested area.

